# R find distance between line and point at fixed bearing angles

Tags: r, r-sf

this is my reproducible example

```
########################################

library(sf)

# matrix of lon lat for the definition of the linestring
m<-rbind(
  c(12.09136, 45.86471),
  c(12.09120, 45.86495),
  c(12.09136, 45.86531),
  c(12.09137, 45.86540),
  c(12.09188, 45.86585),
  c(12.09200, 45.86592),
  c(12.09264, 45.86622),
  c(12.09329, 45.86624),
  c(12.09393, 45.86597),
  c(12.09410, 45.86585),
  c(12.09423, 45.86540),
  c(12.09411, 45.86495),
  c(12.09393, 45.86471),
  c(12.09383, 45.86451),
  c(12.09329, 45.86414),
  c(12.09264, 45.86413),
  c(12.09200, 45.86425),
  c(12.09151, 45.86451),
  c(12.09136, 45.86471)
)

# define a linestring
ls<-st_linestring(m)

# create a simple feature with appropriate crs
ls<-st_sfc(ls, crs=4326)

# and now again going through the very same 
# definition process for a point

# define a point 
pt <- st_point(c(12.09286,45.86557))

# crate simple feature with appropriate crs
pt<-st_sfc(pt, crs = 4326)

plot(ls)
plot(pt, add=TRUE)

# this is computing the minimum distance from the point to the line
st_distance(ls, pt)


###############
```

given the above mentioned toy dataset, I need to find a proper method to calculate:

1 - the distance from each vertex of the line to the given point: and this is probably easily accomplished by calculating the distance between each couple of points (line vetex vs. point) through the simple application of the pythagorean theorem even if I'm quite dubious of that because of the crs in use (i.e. epsg 4326, in degree unit), so that I probably need first to convert the whole dataset to another reference system (with metric unit)...

2 - the distance between the point and the line at fixed bearing angles (10°, 20°, 30°,....,360° from the North): and this is where I'm really lost....

please give me some help in order to properly proceed with the calculation, possibly by using the 'sf' standard that I'm trying now to familiarize with

thanks

Answer (score 5):

thank you for pointing me in the right direction

I worked out my final solution that I'm posting here for the sake of completeness

```
# my reproducible example

library(sf)

# matrix of lon lat for the definition of the linestring
m<-rbind(
  c(12.09136, 45.86471),
  c(12.09120, 45.86495),
  c(12.09136, 45.86531),
  c(12.09137, 45.86540),
  c(12.09188, 45.86585),
  c(12.09200, 45.86592),
  c(12.09264, 45.86622),
  c(12.09329, 45.86624),
  c(12.09393, 45.86597),
  c(12.09410, 45.86585),
  c(12.09423, 45.86540),
  c(12.09411, 45.86495),
  c(12.09393, 45.86471),
  c(12.09383, 45.86451),
  c(12.09329, 45.86414),
  c(12.09264, 45.86413),
  c(12.09200, 45.86425),
  c(12.09151, 45.86451),
  c(12.09136, 45.86471)
)

# define the linestring
ls<-st_linestring(m)

# create a simple feature linestring with appropriate crs
ls<-st_sfc(ls, crs=4326)

# and now again going through the very same 
# definition process for a point

# define the origin point 
pt <- st_point(c(12.09286,45.86557))

# create simple feature point with appropriate crs
pt<-st_sfc(pt, crs = 4326)

plot(ls)
plot(pt, add=TRUE)

# get minimum distance from the origin point to the line
dist_min<-st_distance(ls, pt)

# get cordinates of the origin point
pt_orig<-st_coordinates(pt)

# load library for later use of the function destPoint()
library(geosphere)

# create vector of bearing angles of 10 degress amplitude
b_angles<-seq(0, 350, 10) 

# create empty container for final result as data frame
result<-data.frame(bearing=NULL, distance=NULL)

for(i in 1:length(b_angles)){
  
  result[i,"bearing"]<-b_angles[i]
  
  # calculate destination point coordinates with bearing angle i
  # at fixed safe distance (i.e. 100 times the minimum distance)
  # so that to avoid null intersection in next step calculation
  pt_dest<-destPoint(p=pt_orig, b=b_angles[i],d=dist_min*100)
  
  # define linestring from origin to destination
  b_ls<-st_sfc(st_linestring(rbind(pt_orig, pt_dest)), crs=4326)
  
  # get the intersection point between two features
  pt_int<-st_intersection(ls, b_ls)
  
  # get the distance
  d<-st_distance(pt, pt_int)
  
  result[i,"distance"]<-d
}
```

I stick as much as possible with the "sf" approach which is giving the following warning inside the for loop in correspondace with the execution of st_intersection(): "although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar"

but considering the short distance I'm working with it seems to me an acceptable approximation

by the way, as far as I understand, it does not exists a corresponding function to geosphere::destPoint within the package "sf"

thanks